# Saving RDD as a text file: ExitCodeException

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I was working on PySpark on **Windows** and I stopped when I had this error. Here is just a small example which generates the error:

```
testing = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
testing.saveAsTextFile("Desktop\Testing.txt")
```

And here is the full error that I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-19ab2fb9aaaf> in <module>()
      1 test = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
----> 2 test.saveAsTextFile("Desktop\Test123.txt")

C:\Spark\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in saveAsTextFile(self, path, compressionCodecClass)
   1504             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
   1505         else:
-> 1506             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
   1507 
   1508     # Pair functions

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\py4j-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\py4j\java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Spark\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\py4j-0.10.4-py2.7.egg\py4j\protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1183)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1209)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1060)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1436)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1436)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1436)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:507)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1183)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I searched so much for a solution for this **ExitCodeException** but I couldn't find and I didn't know how to fix it! Then, I kinda gave up and went to do it in a really basic way with normal Python like the following:

```
testt = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
Test1 = open('Desktop\\Test1.txt','w')
testt.map(lambda line: Test1.write(str(line)))
```

But I'm getting also this error:

> PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading

I would appreciate any help to make saving RDD happens!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a full traceback from the first exception.

Comment: Are you sure that path exists and you have write permission?

Comment: Yes, the path does exist because it starts creating the folder and writing the part file ('part-0000'). But since the error occurs, it doesn't finish writing and the file becomes empty or blank. How can I check for the writing permission? @pault

Comment: @Kale If you can create the folder and the part file, then you have permission. Try deleting the folder and running again. I can't remember for sure, but I vaguely remember that the default setting is not to overwrite if the file already exists.

Comment: I did already many time: writing with different names, running many times, deleting and rewriting, changing the path but still the same error occurs @pault

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your error. The `saveAsTextFile()` part works fine for me. As for the second thing, don't write to write to the file inside the `map()` function. The error message is saying that you can't serialize the filestream for writing. Instead, map the records to strings and call `collect()` to write the file: `Test1.write("\n".join(testt.map(str).collect()))`. Maybe this will help you debug.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does starting a streaming query lead to “ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947375/why-does-starting-a-streaming-query-lead-to-exitcodeexception-exitcode-1073741). Perhaps it's a bug with windows.

Comment: Well, it didn't work as you wrote exactly, I modified it. After the second line (Test1), I did this: `Strings=testt.map(lambda line: str(line))` . Then this: `Test1.write(\"\\n\".join(Strings.collect()))` and worked for me. It's true that the error hasn't been solved, but I got what I want at least. Thank you so much :) @pault