# Getting started with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying out pyspark on windows by following [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/quick-start.html) article.
The article asks to run `pyspark` from command prompt.

When I run `pyspark` in command prompt, it starts jupyter notebook. But in example, it seems that running `pyspark` in command line starts interactive command line python shell. Why is this so?

The article next asks to read readme file:

```
>>>textFile = spark.read.text("README.md")
```

I tried running that in jupyter notebook. But I got following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Sanjeev\Programs\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

D:\Sanjeev\Programs\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.text.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: ;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.createDirsWithPermission(Utilities.java:3679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 46 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9f78f301aea9> in <module>()
----> 1 textFile = spark.read.text("README.md")

D:\Sanjeev\Programs\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in text(self, paths, wholetext)
    326         if isinstance(paths, basestring):
    327             paths = [paths]
--> 328         return self._df(self._jreader.text(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(paths)))
    329 
    330     @since(2.0)

D:\Sanjeev\Programs\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

D:\Sanjeev\Programs\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: ;'
```

I am finding absolutely no explanation in that stack trace. Earlier I got stack trace with last line `AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/Mahesha999/README.md;'` which hinted me that I should be running `pyspark` from `%SPARK_HOME%` instead of user directory. But above I am not getting any such hint from stack trace. What am missing?

Comment: you must have environment variable pointing to your jupyter installation

Comment: Please go through this link. Check if this helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947375/why-does-starting-a-streaming-query-lead-to-exitcodeexception-exitcode-1073741

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am having `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` set to `jupyter` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` set to `notebook`. I tried pyspark installation by following some other online tut.  But that went wrong. But I forgot to clear these environment variables. Is it because of these environment variables?

Comment: yes thats right. just change them or just disable them by commenting and you should be fine

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yeah that worked but the actual issue remained. Now I am getting error on python shell. I have asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406977) explaining the issue. Can you have a look at it? The question gives error I get when I run scala code in scala shell, but I have checked that I am getting the same error with pyspark python shell too.

Comment: you should answer it below then  the steps that you followed to solve this issue

Comment: I didnt get you. I have removed those environment variables to make pyspark command open python shell in command prompt instead of opening jupyter notebook. But now I am getting same (that I was getting in notebook) error in python shell.

Comment: Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (vcredist_x64.exe from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)) resolved the issue as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992503/1317018).