# Error Stream metadata using Pyspark in Windows 10 OS

Tags: python, pyspark, twitter, spark-streaming

I am trying to stream the data from Twitter API but unable to execute the code.

Following are the code snippet and error. Please let me know what is the issue if anyone can help here.

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create Spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TwitterSentimentAnalysis").getOrCreate()

    # read the tweet data from socket
    tweet_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("socket") \
        .option("host", "127.0.0.1") \
        .option("port", 3333) \
        .load()

    # type cast the column value
    tweet_df_string = tweet_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")


    # split words based on space, filter out hashtag values and group them up
    tweets_tab = tweet_df_string.withColumn('word', explode(split(F.col('value'), ' '))) \
        .groupBy('word') \
        .count() \
        .sort('count', ascending=False). \
        filter(F.col('word').contains('#'))



    # write the above data into memory. consider the entire analysis in all iteration (output mode = complete). and let the trigger runs in every 2 secs.
    writeTweet = tweets_tab.writeStream\
    .outputMode('complete')\
    .format('console')\
    .start()

    print("----- streaming is running -------")
```

**Error:**

> Error : ERROR StreamMetadata: Error writing stream metadata
> StreamMetadata(ea206b0f-718b-49f5-bd97-9e7488f643cd) to
> file:/C:/Users/aakash%2520uppadhaya/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-41057c59-fcac-4d2e-9a71-a6e53c57c2ec/metadata
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/Users/aakash%2520uppadhaya/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-41057c59-fcac-4d2e-9a71-a6e53c57c2ec
> does not exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does starting a streaming query lead to "ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947375/why-does-starting-a-streaming-query-lead-to-exitcodeexception-exitcode-1073741)