# Print Pyspark Streaming Data from a kafka Topic

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to kafka and pyspark and trying to write simple program , SO I have 2 files in kafka Topics in JSon format and I am reading this from pyspark streaming.

My Producer code is as follows:

```
  from kafka import *
import json
import time
import boto3
import json
from Consumer_Group import *
from json import loads
class producer :
            def json_serializer(data):
                    return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")

            def read_s3():
                p1 = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer=producer.json_serializer)
                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
                bucket = s3.Bucket('kakfa')
                for obj in bucket.objects.all():
                    key = obj.key
                    body = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
                p1.send("Uber_Eats",body)
                p1.flush()
```

My Consumer code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from kafka import *
import time
class consumer:
                def read_from_topic(self,spark):
                        df = spark.readStream \
                            .format("kafka") \
                            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
                            .option("subscribe", "Uber_Eats") \
                             .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
                            .load()
                        df.createOrReplaceTempView("kafka")
                        spark.sql("select * from kafka")
                        print(df.isStreaming())
                                  


                def get_consumer(self):
                    consumer = KafkaConsumer("Uber_Eats", group_id='group1', bootstrap_servers=
                    "localhost:9092")
                    return  consumer

                def print_details(self,c1):
                    #    self.consumer=self.get_consumer(self)
                        # Read and print message from consumer
                     try:
                                for msg in c1:
                                    print(msg.topic, msg.value)
                                print("Done")
                     except Exception  as e:
                                print(e)
```

Main  Class:

```
from Producer_Group import *
from Consumer_Group import *
from Spark_Connection import *
class client:
    def transfer(self):
        spark = connection.get_connection(self)
        producer.read_s3()
        c1 = consumer.get_consumer(spark)
        consumer.read_from_topic(self,spark)
      #  consumer.print_details(self,c1)

c=client()
c.transfer()
```

Sample Data  in S3 that i am reading into kafka Topic :

```
{
    
        {
            "Customer Number": "1",
            "Customer Name": "Aditya",
            "Restaurant Number": "2201",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Bawarchi",
            "Number of Items": "3",
            "price": "10",
            "Operating Start hours": "9:00",
            "Operating End hours": "23:00"
        },
        {
            "Customer Number": "2",
            "Customer Name": "Sarva",
            "Restaurant Number": "2202",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Sarvana Bhavan",
            "Number of Items": "4",
            "price": "20",
            "Operating Start hours": "8:00",
            "Operating End hours": "20:00"
        },
        {
            "Customer Number": "3",
            "Customer Name": "Kala",
            "Restaurant Number": "2203",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Taco Bell",
            "Number of Items": "5",
            "price": "30",
            "Operating Start hours": "11:00",
            "Operating End hours": "21:00"
        }
    
}
```

**What Have I tried so far:** : I have tried to print on console so as to check for condition and if it passes only then insert it into databse. to check the condtiion  , I am reading data from "read_from_topic"  function and creating a view (createOrReplaceTempView) to see data, but nothing is printing, can some one please guide me how to print and verify if My conditions or data is read correclty?

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: I think I've told you before, `KafkaConsumer` and `readStream.format("kafka")` are two completely separate libraries, and you shouldn't use the first if you want to use Spark, and you shouldn't use the second if the only goal is to consume from Kafka... So, can you please clarify your goal? Besides that, you've only shown a class definition that you've never called, so what piece of this code is supposed to print anything?

Comment: I have included "Main class" and sample data (JSON ). Please have a look

So I am trying to read from kafka topic and for each customer there is "Operating Start hours", if it is greater than 8:00 only then I should insert into mysql databse else ignore, this is my requirmenet.

Comment: My goal is to only consume from kafka topic and do transformations in spark streaming and based on that insert into databse

Comment: I mean, Python's `KafkaConsumer` can also "do transformations" and you can combine that with other libraries to "write to databases", so still unclear why you think you'll need Spark for that? Also, I wouldn't even use Python for this since Kafka comes with Kafka Connect for exactly this purpose of writing to external systems https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/ Besides that, what happens when this runs? Because you should actually be getting an error around `consumer.read_from_topic(self,spark)`

Answer (score 1):

> creating a view (createOrReplaceTempView) to see data, but nothing is printing

Because `spark.sql` returns a new Dataframe.

If you want to print it, then you'll need

```
spark.sql("select * from kafka").show()
```

However, this alone will be at least two byte array columns, not JSON strings, so you'll want to [define a schema at some point to extract anything or `CAST` to at least have human readable data](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html)

Also worth pointing out that the data you've shown is not valid JSON, and `boto3` isn't necessary since Spark can read files from S3 itself (and thus Kafka isn't strictly needed since you could just take S3 data directly into your final location, with a Spark `persist()` function in between)

Comment: I am trying to use your .show method that you gave , but is giving me error.

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Comment: Correct. You need to start() and awaitTermination. Here's an example from the Spark source code https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredKafkaWordCount.scala#L83-L90

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, it is giving me a different error,

RROR StreamMetadata: Error writing stream metadata StreamMetadata(68220860-8bb2-4058-8799-64d5ef5fcc7d) to file:/C:/Users/komu0/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-7975a168-d556-4ec3-abfb-f23c8c8508cd/metadata
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:

Comment: I don't know about this. I also don't develop on windows, but seems there's some solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947375/why-does-starting-a-streaming-query-lead-to-exitcodeexception-exitcode-1073741

Comment: sure , Thank you so much